# How to handle multiple LoadMask in Extjs?

Tags: extjs, mask

I'm doing multi-load in one Window (form load and grid data).
This is my logic,

1. Start with do mask when Window open.
2. Add mask-counter in form load and grid load callback.
3. When mask-counter equal 2, unmask.

Do you have better idea ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can also use this logic:

```
form.beforeLoad( form.loading = true, if ( not grid.loading ) mask )
grid.beforeLoad( grid.loading = true, if ( not form.loading ) mask )

form.onLoad( form.loading = false, if ( not grid.loading ) unmask )
grid.onLoad( grid.loading = false, if ( not form.loading ) unmask )
```

this will sync loaders.

by the way, you can also use Ext.Msg.wait, that'll bring a modal dialog without any buttons and wait until you call hide event.